# Unable to get the right response in wordpress custom plugin by jquery ajax post request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am creating my first ever wordpress plugin which simply fetches and inserts data in the database using jQuery AJAX Post method. My Wordpress version is 3.8.1

I was trying to make an AJAX Post request but i got this error message.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in J:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\auc_data_fetcher\includes\fetch-results.php on line 19
```

I saw this post [Stackoverlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410806/wordpress-plugin-calling-database-results-via-ajax) and i added this code at the top of my page where AJAX Post Request posts the form but the third line hides my page.

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-config.php' );
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );

$wpdb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST); //By adding this line hides all the pages.
```

Then i added the below line of code and it worked but there is still some problem. I started getting the same double values in response instead of a single results.

For example:
The response should be `some fetched data from db`.
I am getting `some fetched data from db some fetched data from db` instead of single same result.

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-load.php' );
```

If i do not include the above `wp-load` file, i get the right response but i need to interact with database and removing above include file code again starts giving the same `Fatal error for $wpdb`.

Please help me out to fix my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to post to an external page that isn't part of WordPress?  WordPress has an entire API for handling ajax and will save you the trouble of having to try and include core and get it up and running on a standard php page.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) `/wp-load.php` file.

after that define global $wpdb.

Note that after defining $wpdb you need not to provide password and related credentials again.

And if you are writing and ajax functionality then you have to write this in call_back function where your query execution is gonna happen

forgive me for my english